# Difference in flattening an Option[List[Int]] in 2.9.1 and 2.10 nightly

Tags: scala

I get different behaviour in 2.9.1 and 2.10 nightly -- what changed?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (OpenJDK Client VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Some(3) map (x => List(x, -x)) flatten
res0: List[Int] = List(3, -3)
```

Versus:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0.r26084-b20111129020255 (OpenJDK Client VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Some(3) map (x => List(x, -x)) flatten
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< Option[B].
              Some(3) map (x => List(x, -x)) flatten
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is that Option acquired a `flatten` method in 2.10, that works only on nested `Option`s.

In 2.9, the call to flatten was added by an implicit conversion to `Iterable`, and the result was an `Iterable` (or a subtype thereof, depending on the nested value inside `Option`).

Here's the signature of `flatten` in 2.10:

```
def flatten[B](implicit ev: <:<[A, Option[B]): Option[B]
```

It says: if you can find evidence that the element inside this option is an `Option` itself, say `Option[B]`, I can flatten that and return an `Option[B]`.

Implicits are only tried if there is *no* method with that name, so that explains why it doesn't fall back to the 2.9 method.

Comment: It appears this new `flatten` is more in line with Haskell's monadic `join`; is that the intent?

Comment: Let's hope everyone does thorough regression testing when they upgrade to 2.10!

Comment: Definitely an improvement that Option[Option[X]] can flatten to Option[X], although it's a little bit of a shame about the Iterable case. I suppose a more flexible flatten could be put together with a bit of typeclass machinery, if you really wanted it that badly...

Comment: @DanBurton yes, that's what I think as well.

Comment: @MattR, probably, but then the current `flatten` should be added through an implicit as well. Not sure what's best here, but I can definitely say I find the current behavior more useful in my code.