# Why doesn't Some(List(1,2,3)).flatten compile?

Tags: scala, monads, scala-2.10

In Scala 2.9.1, I could do

```
> Some(List(1,2,3)).flatten
List(1,2,3)
```

But in Scala 2.10.0,

```
> Some(List(1,2,3)).flatten
Cannot prove that Seq[Int] <:< Option[B]
```

I found [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4474) closed bug, but I don't understand the verdict, or why it was closed.

(1) Why doesn't this work in Scala 2.10 (apparently by design?)

(2) What is the idiomatic 2.10 equivalent of my 2.9 code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313802/difference-in-flattening-an-optionlistint-in-2-9-1-and-2-10-nightly?rq=1 is very much related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`flatten` adopts the type of the outer container.  You can't fit a `List` into an `Option`, so that doesn't work.  Instead, change the type of the outer container first so flattening is possible:

```
Some(List(1,2,3)).toList.flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

`flatten` is really only intended to work on a single monad at a time. That is, it transforms `M[M[T]]` into `M[T]`, as in `List(List(1,2),List(3)).flatten => List(1,2,3)`. `scala.Predef` provides implicits to coerce `Option[T]` into `List[T]`, but not the other way around. While it is somewhat reasonable to treat an Option as a List of zero or one elements, there's no general pattern for Lists with two or more elements.

The other way around, however, is supported for convenience:

```
List(Some(1),None,Some(2),Some(3)).flatten => List(1, 2, 3)
```

Edit: i misspoke. it's not an implicit conversion to Option that makes this possible, but rather that `Option` is *traversable*. In [the api docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List), `List`'s `flatten` is actually:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

Comment: `Option` isn't a `Traversable`.  You were *almost* right the first time, it's implicitly converted to an `Iterable`.  If `Option` were traversable then `Option(List(...)).flatten` would be seen as `Traversable(Traversable(...)).flatten` and it would work.